# Mobile navigation bar fixing to screen-top incorrectly

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here is the site in question: [Navigation bar broken on mobile](https://crowley-design-development.github.io/QuackAndWabbit/)

I made the nav bar snap to the top of the screen when the user scrolls past the jumbotron with bootstrap's navbar-fixed-top class, and this works perfectly on large screens, however, on mobile sized screens in chromes' debug environment, the navbar glitches when you scroll past the jumbotron!

To see the problem in action, go to the linked site, right click on chrome and inspect, the resize the window to a mobile size.  If you slowly scroll past the navbar, it breaks!

The script to add the navbar-fixed-top class is shown below.  The added padding fixed a previous problem where the navbar wasn't snapping correctly.

Thanks in advance for the help! :)

```
<!-- JQuery function for navbar-fixed-top and fix navigation top of page jump -->
<script> 
$(document).ready(function() {
// Closes the Responsive Menu on Menu Item Click
$('.navbar-collapse ul li a').click(function(){ 
    $('.navbar-toggle:visible').click();
});

$(window).scroll(function () {
  //if you hard code, then use console
  //.log to determine when you want the 

      var d = $('#jumbo');
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > d.prop("scrollHeight") ) {
      $('#nav_bar').addClass('navbar-fixed-top');
      $('#linkList').addClass('fixed-links');
      $('body').css('margin-top','50px');
    }
    if ($(window).scrollTop() < d.prop("scrollHeight")) {
      $('#nav_bar').removeClass('navbar-fixed-top');
      $('#linkList').removeClass('fixed-links');
      $('body').css('margin-top','0px');
    }
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Try adding to the position fixed navbar -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);

Comment: @santhosh the -webkit-transform didn't seem to work :(